# How to merge 2 data frames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this table1:

```
  A B C D
0 1 2 k l
1 3 4 e r
```

`df.dtypes` gets me this:

```
A int64
B int64
C object
D object
```

Now, I want to create a table2 which only includes objects (column C and D) using this command `table2=df.select_dtypes(include=[object])`.

Then, I want to encode table2 using this command `pd.get_dummies(table)`.

It gives me this table2:

```
  C D
0 0 1
1 1 0
```

The last thing I want to do is append both tables together (table 1 + table 2), so that the final table looks like this:

```
  A B C D
0 1 2 0 1
1 3 4 1 0
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: pd.get_dummies normal returns headers with the data note the column header.  I am not sure what your table2 means?  How exactly did you generate table2?

Comment: does this help? `table1[["A","B"]].merge(table2)`?

Comment: Table2 is a table that ONLY takes the data types "objects" which are a subset of table1's columns as I am trying to convert all categorical variables into numeric, then merge it back with the already numeric columns and then pass it into neural network. Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Look at the output of pd.get_dummies(table2)... it doesn't like that what you represent in your question.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Comment: Just use `table1[['A', 'B']].join(table2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming what you're trying to do from the question is have a column for `C` that has a value of `1` replace values of `e` and in column `D`, values of `1` replace values of `l`. Otherwise, as mentioned elsewhere there will be a column for each response possibility.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2], 'B': [2,4], 'C': ['k','e'], 'D': ['l','r']})

df
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  k  l
1  2  4  e  r

df.dtypes
A     int64
B     int64
C    object
D    object
dtype: object
```

Now, if you want to drop the `e` and `l` because you want to have `k-1` columns, you can use the `drop_first` argument.

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, drop_first = True)
df
   A  B  C_k  D_r
0  1  2    1    0
1  2  4    0    1
```

Note that the dtypes are not `int64` like columns `A` and `B`.

```
df
A      int64
B      int64
C_k    uint8
D_r    uint8
dtype: object
```

If it's important they are the same type you can of course change those as appropriate. In the general case, you may want to keep names like `C_k` and `D_r` so you know what the dummies correspond to. If not, you can always rename based on the `_` (the default of `get_dummies` prefix argument.) So, you could create the rename dictionary using the '_' as as way to split out the part of the column name after the prefix. Or for a simple case like this.

```
df.rename({'C_k': 'C', 'D_r': 'D'}, axis = 1, inplace = True)
df
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  1  0
1  2  4  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
table2=df.select_dtypes(include=[object])
table1.select_dtypes(include=[int]).join(table2.apply(lambda x:pd.factorize(x, sort=True)[0]))
```

[image]

It first factorizes the object typed columns of table 2 (instead of using dummies generator) and then merge it back to the int typed columns of the original dataframe!